# SharePoint CSOM Powershell Taxonomy DLL error while loading

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom, taxonomy

I am getting below error when I load Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll

```
Add-Type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

+ Add-Type -Path $scriptPath"\DLLs\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], ReflectionTypeLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

I have added code as below:

```
Add-Type –Path $scriptPath"\DLLs\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll”
Add-Type –Path $scriptPath"\DLLs\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll”
Add-Type –Path $scriptPath"\DLLs\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll"
```

$scriptPath is the path of my local folder.
I am getting error only for Taxonomy DLL.

Do I need to install any csom components or load the DLLs in a different way for Taxonomy?

Answer (score 0):

Does the dll exists in your folder?

You could download the SDK from below links.

2013:https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585

2016:https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51679

Online:https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038